# Interpreting coxph output with cumulative time dependent covariate

Tags: r, survival, interpretation, cox-model

Hoping for some help in interpreting the `coxph` output in R using the `survival` package. I am very new to R, but have successfully made my way to aggregating my data set and using the `tmerge` function to add in my cumulative time-dependent covariate for a sample size of customers.

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
fit <- coxph( Surv(tstart, tstop, had_event) ~ review_event, data = newdatatestcum)
summary(fit)
```

The output:

```
n= 35695, number of events= 54 

                  coef  exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
review_event -0.006707  0.993316  0.001771 -3.786 0.000153 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

              exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
review_event    0.9933      1.007    0.9899    0.9968

Concordance= 0.693  (se = 0.041 )
Rsquare= 0.001   (max possible= 0.014 )

Likelihood ratio test= 24.1  on 1 df,   p=9.123e-07
Wald test            = 14.34  on 1 df,   p=0.0001529
Score (logrank) test = 11.58  on 1 df,   p=0.0006658
```

Along with this I have used the cox.zph function to test the proportional hazard and from my study so far I do not believe to have violated.

```
cox.zph(fit)
```

The ouput:

```
                 rho chisq     p
review_event -0.0699 0.332 0.564
```

The plot:

```
plot(cox.zph(fit,transform = "log"))
```

[image: cox.zph plot]

Any feedback is very much appreciated as I have come so far only to be unable to interpret anything meaningful after hours of study. Thank you!!

Comment: The N seems exaggerated by the look of the residual plot, and there seems to be a tiny number of events. Are the numbers correct?

Comment: Can you say more about the nature by which Review_event is coded? Do all participants enter the risk set with review_event = 0 and every time there is a review event (say at time $t$), they are censored then re-entered into the risk set at time $t$ with review_event = 1,  and again and again until review_event takes values of, I don't know, 10, 20, 50 or more, and so on until "had_event" occurs. Is that right? had_event is not recurrent correct?

Comment: @YuvalSpiegler you can model low-risk events with the cox model. Another caveat is R does not process subject IDs in TVC analyses. They inflate the "N" substantially but the analyses are not biased, because person-time risk exposure can be pooled across many "observations" in a single participant. Only the deviance loses interpretability.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple answer, if all data is correctly modeled:

> An additional unit of `review_event` will reduce the *hourly/daily/weekly/monthly/yearly* hazard of *event_name* by 0.63% on average.

Note that the proportional assumption indeed holds here.

Comment: Hazards are differentiated with respect to time, they represent instantaneous risks of events.